# Php / Pdo - Get content of every row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hey there I have this table structure:

[image]

Using this code, I want to get the id, the username and the clicks in three variables:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM tracker WHERE username='".$data."'");
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
$id = $row['0'];
$username = $row['1'];
$clicks = $row['2'];
```

My results:

```
$id // slkdflskdfskd
$username // null
$clicks // null
```

My question, why? What am I doing wrong?..

Comment: Right know you are just asking for `username` in your query. Hence you will only get the username

Comment: mhm yea i see, you have any idea about how to configure the syntax?

Comment: `SELECT username, id, clicks,...`  or just `SELECT *` to get everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only retrieving the username column.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM tracker WHERE username='".$data."'");
```

You should change it to include all the columns you want to use:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, username, clicks FROM tracker WHERE username='".$data."'");
```

Also if you wanted to work a bit cleaner you should fetch an associated array. That way you can address your `$row` by column name.

Change

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
```

to

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
```

Then you can select columns from your row like:

```
$row['username'] //slkdflskdfskd
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify those database columns in your `SELECT` statement:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, username, clicks FROM tracker WHERE username='".$data."'");
```

You can also select all using `*`, but it's not considered a best practice, since database structures always change over time. It's kind of lazy. The order of data in the returned array may not match up with the order of variables you're assigning. Etc... Regardless, you should know that if you want to return all columns, you can do this:

```
"SELECT * FROM tracker WHERE username='".$data."'"
```